# Passing one of the parameters in constructor to unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to get/set "testModel.number" in my unit test but I can't seem to get it. When I run the test I get this error message:

```html
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testModelProvider <- testModel
```

Here is the controller:

```html
angular.module("TestApp", [])
    .controller("IndexController", function ($scope, testModel) {
        $scope.name = "test";

        testModel = {
            number: 0
        }

        if (testModel.number === 1) {
            $scope.name = "test1";
        } else {
            $scope.name = "test2";
        }
    });
```

Here is the unit test:

```html
describe('IndexController', function () {
    var scope, createController;

    beforeEach(module("TestApp"));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, testModel) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        createController = function () {
            return $controller('IndexController', {
                '$scope': scope,
                'testModel': testModel
            })
        }
    }));

    it('example test', function () {
        var controller = createController();
        testModel.number = 1;

        expect(scope.name).toBe('test1');
    });
});
```

I'm fairly new to unit testing so any suggestions would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass the `testModel` object to the method creating the controller. Jasmine does not know how to inject custom providers.

```
describe('IndexController', function () {
    var scope, createController;

    beforeEach(module("TestApp"));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        createController = function (testModel) {
            return $controller('IndexController', {
                '$scope': scope,
                'testModel': testModel
            })
        }
    }));

    it('example test', function () {
        var testModel = { number: 1 };
        var controller = createController(testModel);

        expect(scope.name).toBe('test1');
    });
});
```

If you will have multiple tests that will need the `testModel` object, you can also define it at a global level as follows:

```
describe('IndexController', function () {
    var scope, createController;
    var testModel = { number: 1 };

    beforeEach(module("TestApp"));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        createController = function () {
            return $controller('IndexController', {
                '$scope': scope,
                'testModel': testModel
            })
        }
    }));

    it('example test', function () {

        var controller = createController();

        expect(scope.name).toBe('test1');
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome it worked, thanks for showing me these approaches!